# How to expand capybara timeout with remote selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I created a SystemSpec to take a screenshot with remote selenium. This test have three steps.

1. Create 100,000 records
2. Visit /book
3. Take one screenshot

In Step 3, I always detect timed out and I always get screenshot in a few records.

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Books', type: :system do
  before do
    100_000.times do
      Book.create!(price: 200)
    end
  end

  it 'scenario #1' do
    visit books_path
    take_screenshot # always timed out !!!
  end
end
```

```
Failures:

  1) Books scenario #1
     Failure/Error: visit books_path
     
     Net::ReadTimeout:
       Net::ReadTimeout with #<TCPSocket:(closed)>
     
     [Screenshot]: /app/tmp/screenshots/failures_r_spec_example_groups_books_scenario_#1_695.png

     
     # /bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:129:in `response_for'
     # /bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:82:in `request'
     # /bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:64:in `call'
     # /bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:167:in `execute'
     # /bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:567:in `execute'
     # /bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:59:in `get'
     # /bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:32:in `to'
     # /bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:71:in `visit'
     # /bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:278:in `visit'
     # /bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:53:in `call'
     # /bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.33.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:53:in `visit'
     # ./spec/system/books_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I want to expand time to wait for completion of screenshot. How to do this???

I have tried to update waiting time. First, I have added `Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 1200`, but no meaningful. Second, I have update capybara configuration like below, but it is also output error message like this `unknown option: {:"enable-features"=>"NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess"}`

```
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :selenium, using: :headless_chrome, options: {
      browser: :remote,
      'enable-features': 'NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess',
      url: ENV.fetch("SELENIUM_DRIVER_URL"),
      desired_capabilities: :chrome
    }
    Capybara.server_host = 'web'
    Capybara.app_host='http://web'
  end
end
```

### UPDATE

I update books_spec.rb like this to wait rendering, but result is 'timed out'. Rendering /books is about 16 seconds. It is not too long to output 'timed out'.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Books', type: :system do
  before do
    100_000.times do
      Book.create!(price: 200)
    end
  end

  it 'scenario #1' do
    visit books_path
    expect(page).to have_content('New Book')
    take_screenshot
  end
end
```

Comment: From the stacktrace it’s timing out during the visit call, not screenshot. Try pre-compiling your assets in the test environment. Additionally you should have an expectation between `visit` and `screenshot`to ensure the page is in the condition you want before the screenshot

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I have added `expect(page).to have_content('New Book')
    take_screenshot` between `visit` and `screenshot`, but result is timed out. Rendering /books is finished in 16 seconds. It is not too long, isn't it?

Comment: 16 seconds is a long time to wait for a request. If precompiling your assets doesn’t solve that you can pass a `timeout` member of the `options` hash